# Query String How to transfer from url to url

Tags: redirect, mobile, query-string

I have page that is receiving a query string and I want it so that if the user is on a mobile site, it will redirect them to the mobile version of that page and move the query string with it. How would I do this?

Thank is advanced.

Comment: Did my suggestion solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will request forwarding not work in this scenario?

```
  RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(mobileSiteUrl);

  rd.forward(req, resp);
```